# Open Google Colab notebook from URL

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a Python file available under some URL, for example

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/messa/d19ad7fd4dc0f95df9caf984caef127c/raw/4d0daebdcfcf16ea3b7914ee6186bd98dbfb3c20/demo.py

In reality it will not be gist but some courseware/homework review software.

How can I open such URL using [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) so I can for example run the Python code?

I know I can build colab URL for Github gists or repositories, but can I do it for any arbitrary URL?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can of course `!wget` a URL as that, but it seems like there is some larger workflow you are trying to support...

Comment: @BobSmith You would have to open new notebook and type !wget or copy-paste the code or something. But I want the code to just appear in the new Colab notebook, without doing anything more than clicking on a link.

Comment: The simplest way is to put the code in a notebook and then share a link to the notebook. What excludes that approach? Are you seeking a way to convert a `.py` file into a notebook?

Comment: I want to do it automatically. This would be ok it Colab had API for creating new notebook. (What I can do right now is to use Github API to create gist and then generate Colab URL for that gist, because Colab supports Github gists/repos, but that’s not very nice.)

Comment: Imagine you have dozens of homework submissions in form of small python files in some web app. I would like to provide a way to run them in Colab as easy and quick as possible. Just click somewhere and open that file in Colab. Or possibly in some Colab alternative.

Answer (score 15):

There is currently no way to do what you are asking for – to construct a URL that will cause Colab to automatically load the contents of a .py file at a particular URL into a new Colab notebook.

The closest thing to this is to host a notebook on github, and then use a Colab url to open it: (updated based on https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/main/notebooks/colab-github-demo.ipynb#scrollTo=K-NVg7RjyeTk) e.g.

- `http://github.com/username/repository/path/to/notebook.ipynb` can be opened in Colab using `http://colab.research.google.com/github/username/repository/blob/main/path/to/notebook.ipynb`
- `http://gist.github.com/username/hash/filename.ipynb` can be opened in Colab using `http://colab.research.google.com/gist/username/hash/filename.ipynb`

Comment: As of June 2021, it seems it is still not possible to open Jupyter notebook files (.ipynb) from an URL in Google Colab. Here is a [Feature Request in the Google Colab's repo](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1305). Chip in with your votes there so the issue gets some visibility.